# Can a recursive call in defer be optimized by the compiler?

Tags: go, tail-recursion

Let's say I have this function:

```
func abc(i int) (e error) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            abc(i * 2)
        }
    }()

    if someCondition(i) {
      return fmt.Errorf("Some Err");
    }

    return action() // returns err (nil in case of success) or panics
}
```

Will this be considered a tail-recursive call? Can it be optimized by the compiler, as tail-recursive calls may be optimized?

I understand that suppressing panic in such a way is not a good decision, but assume there is a correct `condition()` function, which is safe and correctly determines when to quit.

Comment: you could try to get <site title> with a code like that, which would mean non-optimized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things to say here:

- `recover()` will get value passed to a `panic`. In your case, unless `someCondition` panics, `recover` will always return nil. So I'm not sure what you are trying to do.
- Go doesn't do tail call optimization, the go team prefers meaningful stacktraces. There are discussions about it but nothing agreed yet.

If what you are trying to do is multiply i * 2 until condition is true, then just do:

```golang
// using recursion
func abc(i int) error {
    if err := someCondition(i); err != nil {
      return abc(i * 2);
    }
    return nil
}

// using loop
func abc(i int) error {
    for someCondition(i) != nil {
        i *= 2
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: No, I actually wanted to just clarify, whether it can be optimized by the compiler. The example is artificial. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, in go, it's better if you can write a loop implementation as recursion won't have TCO, so performance won't be as good as a loop. I find it a bit disappointed as many algorithm are much easier and readable when implemented with recursion. There is a proposal for Go 2 to add a `become` keyword which would explicitely do TCO.

Answer (score 2):

> Will this be considered as a tail-recursive call?

No.

> Can it be optimized by the compiler as tail-recusrsive calls may be optimized?

No.

Don't do that. Such cleverness is ungo.

Comment: Well, basically everything here is fishy. 1. The Go compiler does not do any unrolling of tail-recursion, and especially not with defered functions. 2. You are probably trying to be clever here (just assuming, I really have **no** **idea** what your code is trying to do!) and clever is the opposite of understandable; write understandable, straight forward code.

Comment: 3. The recursion happens during recovering from a **panic**. If this recursion ends does **not** depend on a "condition() function, which is safe and correctly determines when to quit". This recursion ends **if** **and** **only** if `abc(i*2)` does not panic (while abc(i) did panic). If `abc(0)` panics than `abc(2*0)` will panic too (assuming it is deterministic), looping endlessly until SO.

Comment: 4. Defered statements run when the function returns. So doing some tail recursion here is basically impossible because when you get rid of the recursive function call you would also get rid of each defered statement, replacing a long chain of defered statements with just one. That simply does not make any sense.

Comment: I suppose you are simply using defer and recover wrong.

Comment: I think "ungo" is a great argument. And I love that word now. lol

Comment: @Volker, thank you for the explanation. Actually, the example is just artificial, I wanted to know, whether this call can be optimized. You answered it completely in: "The Go compiler does not do any unrolling of tail-recursion, and especially not with defered functions".